# Connection to docker container failing because of postgis port issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postgis

My docker container is able to successfully build but when I enter the command `docker-compose build`, the following error is returned:

```
Starting docker_etl_1 ... 
Starting 1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_docker_postgis_1 ... 
Starting 1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_docker_postgis_1
Starting 1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_docker_postgis_1 ... error

ERROR: for 1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_docker_postgis_1  Cannot start service postgis: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_docker_postgis_1 (91464afbee8bf7212061797ec0f4c017a56cc3c30c9bdaf513127a6e6a4a5a52): Error starting userland prStarting docker_etl_1 ... done

ERROR: for postgis  Cannot start service postgis: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_1e5f56853e10_docker_postgis_1 (91464afbee8bf7212061797ec0f4c017a56cc3c30c9bdaf513127a6e6a4a5a52): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed: port is already allocated
```

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgis:
    build: ./postgis
    volumes:
      - ../src/main/sql:/sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  etl:
    build: ./etl
    volumes:
      - ..:/national-voter-file
    entrypoint:
      - python3
      - /national-voter-file/load/loader.py
```

and here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mdillon/postgis:9.5

ENV POSTGRES_DB VOTER

RUN  mkdir /sql
COPY ./dockerResources/z-init-db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 5432
```

`Docker ps -a` returns:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
da74ad97b95c        docker_postgis      "docker-entrypoint..."   About a minute ago   Created                                             docker_postgis_1
5872c6e55fe2        docker_etl          "python3 /national..."   About a minute ago   Exited (2) About a minute ago                       docker_etl_1
```

However, when I try `rm $(docker ps -qa)` I get the following error:

```
rm: da74ad97b95c: No such file or directory
rm: 5872c6e55fe2: No such file or directory
```

I don't believe I have another container running so I'm confused by the message `Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed: port is already allocated`

Comment: You can just check if anything is bound to that port - `lsof -i4 | grep 5432`, etc.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That command doesn't return anything. Should it?

Comment: it sounds like you have _something_ running on your system that is already taking up port 5432. Is it possible you have a postgres instance already running on your host?

Comment: @programmerq that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you ran the same docker-compose earlier, which probably failed or at least failed to clean up the services? 
Try running `docker ps -a` to check if any stopped containers exist. It is possible that the stopped containers are hogging the port. If so, just clear them out using `docker rm $(docker ps -qa)`

Comment: I've updated my question with the output of those commands. Why can't the remove command find the correct files?